# What does Tee hee mean?

Tags: meaning

https://www.lingq.com/lesson/lesson-27-using-humor-in-a-speech-431422/

COMEDIAN:

The easiest way to find out if your speech is funny is to practice on people before you make it. If it’s not funny, you’ll soon know. But if it is, you’ll get a laugh. Now, if it’s a small laugh, like a Tee hee - a titter - then maybe they’re just being polite. If it’s a proper belly laugh, then you know your joke really is funny.

What does Tee hee mean? There are some definitions on the dictionaries, but none of them are clear. I need some examples. I need to watch and hear a Tee-hee to understand the meaning. Are there any video on the web to watch and hear a Tee hee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many sounds we make but don't recognize when they are interpreted as text. Take for example [Mwahaha](https://www.google.ps/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mwahahaha&ved=2ahUKEwjtnanojsjgAhUnDWMBHUiVCfIQFjABegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1ZlDK-zGzUNfC8UHZ0cUYs) -- It is a devilish laugh that if we laughed, neither we nor the *audience* would notice the first part of it, the **Mw**.

I would consider [Tee hee](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tee-hee) as merely a laugh (a giggle) which would be in reality **Hehe**.

**PS**: I found a video where the presenter laughed a "Tee hee" laugh which lasted exactly one second at [0:56](https://youtu.be/Qu_fNTNbhwE?t=56). You will find him providing "Tee hee" as a **word**, not a **laugh**, all the video long except for that second where you may not notice the 'T' clearly. So, repeat it until you catch it somehow.

Also, here is a [GIF image](https://giphy.com/gifs/orchfilms-espionage-tonight-l378lOsfG4cMhmYE0/fullscreen) from an Indian movie. It is, of course, with no sound, but after hearing the laugh in the video, you would be able to imagine it happening in the picture with the body language of the actor.

A *side* note: I don't know the name of the movie; otherwise, I would have attached it.

Comment: I wonder if someone can show me a tee-hee in a video? I think the best definition for tee-hee is to watch and to hear an example of it?

Comment: I have updated my answer by attaching several materials that I hope would help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tasneem Zh. NOW I can understand what is tee hee

Answer (score 3):

"Tee hee" is an example of "onomatopoeia", a word that resembles the sound it is describing. If you say "tee hee", or a similar sound, then you're more or less making the sound that it describes.

[EDIT to remove the statement that it's not a noun, I stand corrected]

Comment: But you can see        https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tee-hee     and there tee-hee is identified as a noun and as a verb.

Comment: There's also the old joke of a person attending a trial in a Third World country, and observing a man moving through the crowd, grabbing women's breasts whenever the judge makes a joke. Asking his host what was going on, the host  replies, "Well, whenever we read about trials in _____, we see, "A titter ran through the crowd.""